# How can I install my own Extension? Vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I made my own Extension pack using Yeoman Generator, but I can't figure out how to install it on my vscode.

Maybe if I export my extension pack to the Marketplace it will be possible, but I dont want to do that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can manually install your extension by placing the extension directory in `/home/your-username/.vscode/extensions/` (in OS X / Linux) or the equivalent directory in Windows (just guessing but maybe `/Users/your-username/.vscode`).

Comment: Now is not working anymore...

Comment: @David Same here. Seems like as of now we have to package our extension first using `vsce` and then install the resulting `.vsix` file (https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/publishing-extension#packaging-extensions).

Comment: I do manually install with a subfolder

Answer (score 9):

You can [package an extension into a vsix file](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/publishing-extension#packaging-extensions) that you can install yourself or distribute to others.

To package your extension, in your extension directory run:

```
$ vsce package
```

This will produce a `vsix` file called something like `my-extension-0.0.1.vsix`.

Then run `code --install-extension my-extension-0.0.1.vsix` from the command line or use the `Install from VSIX` command in the extensions view (under the `...`) to install your extension:

[image: Install from vsix]

Comment: Though you will need a Personal access tokens for this option.

Comment: `npm install -g vsce`

Comment: npm WARN deprecated vsce@2.15.0: vsce has been renamed to @vscode/vsce. Install using @vscode/vsce instead.
`npm install -g  @vscode/vsce`